# Insert txt or csv file into mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

kindly we need your support as we face the below issue while inserting text file into mysql.
I have 2 db server.
In the first, when execute the following commands to insert txt or csv file into a table, it's work without any issue.

```
load data local infile '/root/file.csv' into table my_table;

load data local infile '/root/file.txt' into table my_table LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

When I execute the same commands (with the same parameters) in the same table being on another database server, it dont work.

For the first command :

```
load data local infile '/root/file.csv' into table my_table;
```

it shows me the following result :

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'GRP_DBID' cannot be null
>   or the GRP_DBID into the file is not null

and when i execute the second command :

```
load data local infile '/root/file.txt' into table my_table LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

it shows me the following relust :

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'ACTIVITY' cannot be null

where the 'ACTIVITY' column does not exist into the txt file and the database

I need your help please

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154105/error-1048-23000-column-cannot-be-null-however-i-am-inserting-valid-data

Comment: Ok, so if you want help we will need to see the Schema for the table you are loading and also a reasonable cross section of records from the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqlimport to load file into the database table in mysql

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
            --fields-terminated-by=, \
            --local -u root \
            -p Database \
             File.csv
```